# Code works on MinGW but not on my uni's computer (Language C)

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, mingw

I have to make a program that calculates the integral of a function using the simpsons method and the trapezoid method. It works just fine on my computer using MinGW, but when I try to compile it in my uni's computer I get:

```
It = 0 //should be 0.954499
*pn = 0 //should be 18
Is = 0 //should be 0.954500
*pn = 0 //should be 6
```

This is what I came up with (sorry the variables and comments are in portuguese, I'll fix it later after I get home):

integral.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define eps 1.e-6
#define kmax 20

double trapezio(double (*f)(double x), double a, double b, int *n);
double simpson(double (*f)(double x), double a, double b, int *n);
```

integral.c:

```
#include "integral.h"
#define xmin -2
#define xmax 2

double f(double x);

int main(){
    double It,Is;
    int n = 0;
    int *pn = NULL;

    pn = &n;
    It = trapezio(f,xmin,xmax,pn)/sqrt(2*M_PI);
    printf("Pelo metodo dos trapezios a integral vale aproximadamente %lf\n", It);
    printf("O numero de iteracoes usadas foi %d\n\n",*pn);

    *pn = 0;
    Is = simpson(f,xmin,xmax,pn)/sqrt(2*M_PI);
    printf("Pelo metodo de simpson a integral vale aproximadamente %lf\n", Is);
    printf("O numero de iteracoes usadas foi %d\n",*pn);

    return 0;
}

double f(double x){
    return exp(-0.5*x*x); // Funcao que sera integrada
}
```

trapezio.c:

```
#include "integral.h"

double trapezio(double (*f)(double x), double a, double b, int *n){
    double To, Tk;
    double soma;
    int i, k = 1;
    Tk = 0.5*(f(a) - f(b))*(b - a);

    while (fabs((Tk-To)/To) > eps && k < kmax){
        soma = 0; // Resetando variavel soma
        To = Tk; // To e' T(k - 1), caso o loop se repita o ultimo Tk vira To
        for (i = 1 ; i <= (pow(2,k)-1) ; i += 2) soma += f(a + i*(b - a)/pow(2.,k));
        Tk = 0.5*To + soma*(b - a)/pow(2.,k);
        k++;
        *n += 1;
    }

    return Tk;
}
```

simpson.c:

```
#include "integral.h"

double simpson(double (*f)(double x), double a, double b, int *n){
    double So, Sk = 0;
    double somaimp, somapar;
    int i, k = 1;

    while (fabs((Sk-So)/So) > eps && k < kmax){
        somaimp = 0;
        somapar = 0;
        So = Sk; // So e' S(k - 1)
        for (i = 1; i <= (pow(2,k)-1); i += 2) somaimp += f(a + i*(b - a)/pow(2.,k));
        for (i = 2; i <= (pow(2,k)-2); i += 2) somapar += f(a + i*(b - a)/pow(2.,k));
        Sk = (b - a)*(f(a) + 4*somaimp + 2*somapar + f(b))/(3*pow(2.,k));
        k++;
        *n += 1;
    }

    return Sk;
}
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that if I take the pointer out, trapezio works, but simpson still returns 0.

Comment: What's the OS and compiler on your uni's computer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `trapezio()`, you never initialize `To` before using it in the `while` loop:

```
double To, Tk;
/* ... no assignment to To ... */
while (fabs((Tk-To)/To) > eps && k < kmax){
```

This means it will behave in an undefined way, and probably never enters the loop at all.

Comment: I thought that since I defined To right after the loop started there'd be no problem, but I forgot the loop condition depended on To. Thanks. :)

Comment: Recent MSVC compilers will warn about this by default (at least since VS 2005). Interestingly, I can't get gcc to warn about this particular case even with `-Wuninitialized  -Wmaybe-uninitialized`.

Comment: Why did my code work on MinGW, though? Did it consider my while loop a do/while loop? That's weird.

Comment: Aha - to get gcc to warn about this you have to have at least some optimization (`-O1`) enabled in addition to the `-Wuninitialized`. That's actually mentioned in the gcc docs, but it's certainly not something I would have expected.

Comment: @NatashaRocha: the nature of undefined behavior is that it can appear to work, too. In your 'good' runs, the `To` variable happened by chance to have some sensible value in it.